# InvalidRegistration error with GCM (Android) and PhoneGap

Tags: android, cordova, google-cloud-messaging, phonegap-plugins

I am using `phonegap-plugin-push` with Android. Although I'm successful in registering the device, I cannot successfully deliver a notification using the `registrationId` returned by the plugin.

```
  var push = PushNotification.init({
    android: {
      senderID: "XXXXXXXXXXXX"
    }
  });

  push.on('registration', function (data) {
    alert('registrationId: ' + data.registrationId);
  });
```

The alert upon registration reads `registrationId: dYeoRp-FIWc:APA91bExJIUVGgpqOh8NNRJ7Ua9vHun7ECN8JWBisFTzrxRYbC1C4cjEpnNsmxzCd7f0o8Hu6Fhp-nrQa5Efw95vtduJKi_o9H2NxeOJUCSX10z48sgDxWmHU7LVbOBa-vZjZVwouhc9`.

An attempted push returns the following:
`{"multicast_id":6855504054873897650,"success":0,"failure":1,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"error":"InvalidRegistration"}]}`

Answer (score 0):

What are you using to send the push notification? Whatever tool you're using may not like the special characters in the registrationId.